CrateDB query to the table with array of objects
I'm looking to query a table which has a column with datatype object_array.
Sample data looks like -
Object_array sample data of single row -

{propertyname=PrimitiveProperty1Type1, intvalue=88, datatype=Integer}     {propertyname=PrimitiveProperty2Type2, intvalue=20, datatype=Integer}     {propertyname=PrimitiveProperty2Type3, intvalue=40, datatype=Integer}     {propertyname=PrimitiveProperty2Type4, intvalue=50, datatype=Integer}     {propertyname=PrimitiveProperty2Type5, intvalue=66, datatype=Integer}

Table data -
Row 1 - int data_1,string data_2, object_array data_3 (assume 5 objects are there 'above sample data').
.
Row N
Now when I query the table like -

select * from table_name  where 'PrimitiveProperty2Type2' ilike ANY(data_3['propertyname'])  and '40' > ANY(data_3['intvalue']) ;

Actual result - It returns the result.
Expected result - It should not return the result. Reason being there is no data in object array where propertyname = PrimitiveProperty2Type2 greater then intvalue = 40;
